# urxvt font size can't be changed on installed fonts

Tags: linux, bash, fonts, urxvt

.Xresources config:

```
URxvt.font: xft:bitocrafull
URxvt.letterSpace: -1
```

and the text becomes extremely small and unreadable. Using

```
URxvt.font: xft:bitocrafull:size=25:pixelsize=25
```

doesn't change the size at all. The font is installed and in ~/.fonts/ and it exists in the "fc-list". Any idea how to change the size of the font?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m02NO.png